# Why query not working?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, sql-delete, sql-like

I am running this code on a php file where many other queries  run but this one does not delete what I need.

Do you know why?

```
$fivesdrafts = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE urlrequested LIKE %s","'%rate=%'") );
```

Comment: Does it throw an error? Too little detail here.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need to wrap %s in single quotes...

```
....WHERE urlrequested LIKE '%s'...
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: The wrapping already happens in the passed parameter. See the single quotes before and after the percent sign in the second parameter of `prepare`.

Comment: Yes I saw that, but just as its not working, I am suggesting to put those quotes in the query format and remove from the parameter